# How can i save the Graphics as gif file on the hard disk?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code:

```
using (backbuffer = D3Ddev.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono))
            {
                using (g = backbuffer.GetGraphics())
                {
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    g.FillPie(myBrush, 256F - distanceFromCenterPixels, 255F - distanceFromCenterPixels,
                    distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, angleF - 23F, 46F);
                    if (angleF < 360)
                        g.(@"c:\coneimages\" + angleF + ".gif");
                }
            }
```

g.Save is not the right way.
But somehow i want to save the Pie the FillPie as gif file on the hard disk.

Comment: What do you mean `g.Save()` is not the right way? You may need to consider your color palette if it's only a GIF you need. PNG is easier to deal with

Comment: I need gif. I mean that g.Save() does nothing i need it will not save it as gif on the hard disk in the location i wanted. Anyway g.Save() is not the solution.

Comment: D3Ddev is part of directx. It's DirectX.Direct3D.Device

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check this class out: [Image.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

And check out this post describing how to convert Graphics to an Image.
[convert Graphics to Image in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891346/convert-graphics-to-image-in-c-sharp)