# Take screenshot and show it in form

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to create a screenshot like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363008/4684797):

```
private Graphics takeScreenshot()
{
    //Create a new bitmap.
    var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
    var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

    // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0,
                                0,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    return gfxScreenshot;
}
```

How can I show it in my form after it is taken?
I tried to display it inside a pictureBox:

```
Graphics screenshot = takeScreenshot();
pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
```

But I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Graphics'
>   to 'System.Drawing.Image' SRAT    C:\Users\Edd\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\SRAT\SRAT\Form1.cs  20  Active

and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891393/4684797) says that it is not possible to convert it

Comment: Don't return the `Graphics`, return `bmpScreenshot` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Graphics` object is a sort of wrapper around an image that lets you draw on the image. They are usually temporary, and don't actually own the pixels that you're drawing.

In your case, `gfxScreenshot` is just providing the ability to draw onto `bmpScreenshot`, which is where the image actually lives in memory.

You should throw away the `Graphics` and return the `Bitmap`:

```
private Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
{
    //Create a new bitmap.
    var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
    using (var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
    {    
        // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0,
                                0,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);    
    }

    return bmpScreenshot;
}
```

Then you can assign the bitmap to a `PictureBox`:

```
Bitmap screenshot = TakeScreenshot();
pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! Now I have an idea how this works.